# How to use int and increase it's value in different code lines

Tags: java, int

I have to initialize a sqlite database that have a structure like this:

Table: Family

Table: SubFamily

Table: Product

One family can have more than one subfamily and and the same for subfamilies with products.

So what i'm doing is:

```
int index_family = 1;
        int index_subfamily = 1;
        int index_product = 1;
//Productos Familia Pavimentos
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Family VALUES (" + index_family + ",'" + R.string.f1_pavimentos + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.color_pavimento + "');");

        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO SubFamily VALUES (" + index_subfamily + "," + index_family + ",'" + R.string.f1s1_nivelantes + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "');");
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (" + index_product + "," + index_subfamily + ",'" + R.string.f1s1p1_ni10 + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "','" + url + "');");
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (" + (index_product + 1) + "," + index_subfamily + ",'" + R.string.f1s1p2_ni80 + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "','" + url + "');");
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (" + (index_product + 2) + "," + index_subfamily + ",'" + R.string.f1s1p3_beL15 + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "','" + url + "');");
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (" + (index_product + 3) + "," + index_subfamily + ",'" + R.string.f1s1p4_beL30 + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "','" + url + "');");
        sqlDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (" + (index_product + 4) + "," + index_subfamily + ",'" + R.string.f1s1p5_beP + "','" + R.string.f0_descripcion + "','" + R.drawable.nivelante80 + "','" + url + "');");
```

The problem is that the value of any index will increase all the time, and in a future will be added more products and families.

I want to know if there is some way more efficient that use for example this approach I did: `(index_product + 1) ; (index_product + 2); ...` without to use `+N` because in a future products (or families,subfamilies) will be added and deleted. And with a lot of products (more than 100) could be very dangerous this way.

Hope I explain my problem.

Comment: Use `++index_product` (increment then use) or `index_product++` (use then increment). Alternatively use a select statement to select the highest index and add 1 to it.

Comment: So is `index_product` expected to increase at each insert?

Comment: Why can't you let the database handle it? I think it can assign unique values to each row incrementally.

Comment: Never build up SQL as strings, please always use parametrized queries! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @npinti  at this moment on the project: yes.  Are more or less 100 products right now. Codebender because the boss wants like that... ¬¬ (I know.. is not the more eficient) He told me that is because in a future they wil change al the ID of the products (they will asign arbitrary id, and not incremental). Thanks Tomas I'll try and tell you something.

Comment: best way would be using a sequence or autoincrement columns in your database rather than handle it via code. like [this](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from what your boss is saying, it might make more sense to have a table for products, sub families and what have you and use foreign keys to take care of everything. Thus, each parent will have a foreign key pointing to all their children.

If you use an ORM, this would very likely be done automatically behind the scenes.

Also as @Weston mentioned, avoid string concatenation within SQL statements. As is your application is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Perhaps you could also suggest an autoincrement field, as I'm not sure you're addressing the core question of how to increment and manage primary keys.

Comment: @Martin: That would make sense, but the OP said that the boss, in turn said, that the ID's might be replaced with non incremental ID's.

Comment: Ok, I'll talk with him to try to change it. (Hope I have luck ^^ ). And I'll chane the sql statements. Forget about SQLInjection. Thanks for all mates! (at this moment to follow working a bit meanwhil boss takes the decision... the solution of @Thomas is working for me )

Comment: @Npinti Indeed, I'd suggest a way to manage primary keys, as well as suggesting something like having more than one candidate key for the table. That addresses the autoincrement/primary key issue and offers a solution to the boss.

Comment: @Shudy: I would recommend you and your boss sit down together and decide what structure will the DB have. It is important you design as best as you possibly could. Keep in mind that in certain applications, the database itself (and the data contained within) could be more expensive that the system as a whole. If you design your system with buts and maybes you could be in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: @npinti Thanks I talked with him, and we will have a meeting in a day, soo.. i'll stop doing anything more to avoid as you said, nasty surprise. Lets see what he "wants" ^^

Comment: @Shudy: Please do. Primary keys are a core design functionality and should be one of those things which when decided upon, shouldn't be changed, *ideally* at least.